# ACCEPT Multiple Variables into SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to have a user enter a list of values into an ACCEPT in SQL Developer?
i.e.:

```
ACCEPT USER_ENTRY CHAR PROMPT 'Please enter values'

select *
from my_table
where my_id in('&USER_ENTRY')
```

Of course this works with a single value but I cannot find a solution to make it work with multiple values. For example if I wanted to select the details for ID '1' and '2'.

I am aware of loading the information into a temporary table and querying against that, but I'd rather avoid that if possible due to the nature of the project (users will call this script using a 'front end' script using `@"MY_FILE_LOCATION\MY_SCRIPT.sql";` and so will not be able to see the actual script that they are running but will need to enter multiple values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDs are numeric, **not** strings, then the user can actually enter a comma-separated list of IDs if the script is like this:

```
ACCEPT USER_ENTRY CHAR PROMPT 'Please enter values (separate by commas)'

select *
from my_table
where my_id in(&USER_ENTRY);
```

If the user enters `1,5,76` then the query actually run will be:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_id in(1,5,76);
```

The same would work for strings in fact, but the user would have to provide the quotes e.g. `'A1','B6','F88'` to get:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_id in('A1','B6','F88');
```

This puts the onus on your users to enter the data correctly - but then SQL Developer was never intended to be an end-user interface, it is a tool for **developers** as its name implies!